# Who coined the term Orthonormal?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

Does anyone know who coined the term orthonormal to refer to a basis that is orthogonal and normal?

In such a poorly named mathematical world (looking at you, conditionally convergent series) I think we should shine more light on good naming, such as orthonormal. Some may argue that it can be confused with orthogonal, but to that I say just be better. It's concise, it sounds nice, and it is very very intuitive.

So if anyone knows the mathematician who popularized the term I would be forever grateful; all you get when you look it up is the Gram-Schmidt process (no disrespect to my boys Gram and Schmidt tho, they're G's fr)

Thank you

Comment: The *Oxford English Dictionary* has a quotation from 1928.  I doubt this is the first use, however.   *Proc. National Acad. Sci. U.S.A.* **14** 911

Comment: Earliest mention of "orthonormal" in zbMATH is https://zbmath.org/35.0436.03, a paper by Stekloff from 1904.  I do not know whether the word "orthonormal" was mentioned in the paper, or merely added on later as a keyword by zbMATH .

Comment: Cornell University Comptroller's Report for the fiscal year ended June 30, 1927, p. [[5](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cornell_University_Announcements/_H3FGOA42u4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PT5&printsec=frontcover)]: " *183. Analysis III: Banach Spaces: 1 Q. Spring. 5 cr. Prerequisite, Mathematics 182. Selected topics from among linear operators, Banach spaces, complete and orthonormal sets of functions and expansions.* "

Comment: Probably not the first - From the (1867) [Transactions of the American Society of Civil Engineers](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Transactions_of_the_American_Society_of/CXJRAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22orthonormal%22&dq=%22orthonormal%22&printsec=frontcover) : "*The $\phi$_r-values constitute a complete orthonormal set...*".

Comment: See also [googe ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22orthonormal%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdefK76_2M8q__U-T6DY6hzh6hOGoQ:1681237619895&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGqPeYuqL-AhWhIjQIHcvFCY4QpwV6BAgBECk&biw=1863&bih=937&dpr=1) for other examples from the 19th century..

Comment: @nwr ... Transactions of the American Society of Civil Engineers.  Maybe.  Or maybe 1867 s when this journal began, while the quotation is from a later year...

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes, I was also surprised by that search result.  Google books is not entirely reliable in this regard.  After a bit of further snooping, it turns out that *Transactions* was first published in 1872.